# Como retornar para a View os itens checados pela CheckBox?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, view

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em ASP.net MVC. No meu form de cadastro, tenho uma checkbox onde seleciono os itens que gostaria de adicionar no BD. O meu form de editar, tenho que obter esses itens checados e mostrar na view: todos os itens que estão na grid e os campos que foram selecionados que estão salvos no BD. Gostaria de retornar para a View todos os itens checados que estão salvos no BD.

O código está assim:

```
@using Forte.Rastreador.ViewModels
@using GridMvc.Html

@model SuperModulosPerfilUsuarioViewModel

<fieldset>
    @Html.Label("Nome do Perfil: ")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Descricao)
    <br /><br />
</fieldset>

<fieldset> //minha checkBOX
    <legend>Modulos do Sistema</legend>

    @Html.Grid(Model.ModulosSistemas).Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Add()
            .Encoded(false)
            .Sanitized(false)
            .SetWidth(30)
            .RenderValueAs(o => Html.CheckBox("Checked", @Model.Check, new { value = o.CodModulo }));

        columns.Add(u => u.DesModulo)
          .Titled("Modulos Perfil")
          .Encoded(false);
    })

</fieldset>
<br /><br />
```

Controller:

```
//Action metodo get Editar, onde retorna todo o conteudo de visualizacao para a view.
public ActionResult EditarPerfilUsuario(int CodPerfil)
{

        var perfilUsuario = PerfilUsuarioRepositorio.ObterPerfilUsuarioPorCodigo(CodPerfil);
        var perfilUsuarioVM = new SuperModulosPerfilUsuarioViewModel();
        perfilUsuarioVM.Descricao = perfilUsuario.Descricao;
        perfilUsuarioVM.ModulosSistemas = ModulosSistemaRepositorio.ListarModulosSistemas();
        perfilUsuarioVM.ModulosDoPerfil = ModulosPerfilRepositorio.ListarModulosDoPerfisPorCodPerfil(CodPerfil);

        foreach (var ms in perfilUsuarioVM.ModulosSistemas)
        {                
            foreach (var mp in perfilUsuarioVM.ModulosDoPerfil)
            {
                if (ms.CodModulo == mp.CodModulo)
                {
                    perfilUsuarioVM.Check = true;
                }
            }                
         }

        return View("EditarPerfilUsuario", perfilUsuarioVM);
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModulosSistema> ListarModulosSistemas()    //metodos listar que se encontram no meu repositorio
    {
        return this.Context.ModulosSistemas;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModulosDoPerfil> ListarModulosDoPerfisPorCodPerfil(int CodPerfil)
    {
        return this.Context.ModulosDoPerfil.Where(c=>c.CodPerfil==CodPerfil);
    }
```

Comment: Tem alguma maneira de fazer isso sem usar a gridmvc??

fazendo na view com foreach???

Comment: Qual versão do MVC você está utilizando?

Answer (score 0):

Infelizmente eu particulamente acho ruim trabalhar com checkboxes e radiobuttons com MVC, porem uma das maneiras que utilizo eu montei este exemplo para lhe ajudar.
Segue um exemplo que eu fiz utilizando os helpers do MVC:

Código do controle:

```
     public class DisplayCheckBox
     {
        public int Valor { get; set; }
        public string Texto { get; set; }
        public bool Selecionado { get; set; }
     }

     public class FiltroController : Controller
     {
        public List<DisplayCheckBox> TodosChecks = new List<DisplayCheckBox>();

        public FiltroController()
        {
           for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
           {
              TodosChecks.Add(new DisplayCheckBox { Valor = i, Texto = "Nome " + i.ToString(), Selecionado = (i % 2 == 0) });
           }
        }

        //
        // GET: /Filtro/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
           return View(new Formulario { Nome = "Teste", checados = TodosChecks });
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Formulario modelo)
        {
           return View(modelo);
        }
     }

     public class Formulario
     {
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public List<DisplayCheckBox> checados { get; set; }
     }
```

Código da view:

```
  @model MVCApp.Controllers.Formulario

  @using (Html.BeginForm())
  {
     <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="col-md-12">
           @Html.EditorFor(modelitem => modelitem.Nome)
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
           <ul>
              @for (int i = 0; i < Model.checados.Count; i++)
              {
                 <li>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelitem => Model.checados[i].Selecionado)
                    @Model.checados[i].Texto

                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelitem => Model.checados[i].Valor)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelitem => Model.checados[i].Texto)
                 </li>
              }
           </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">
           <button class="btn" type="submit">Salvar</button>
        </div>
     </div>
  }
```

Obs: No exemplo eu carrego apenas os pares selecionados ( seriam os do seu banco de dados ) e cada post ele envia o modelo com a propriedade selecionado == true para aqueles selecionados!

Espero ter ajudado!!